# NoSuchMethodError: The method 'getdecodedMap' was called on null

Tags: flutter, dart, localization

Problem when calling FlutterI18.translate from the **FlutterI18n plugin** for Flutter localization.

I tried implementing localization using the flutterI18 plugin on my flutter app but keep facing this problem when trying to call the **translate function of the Flutter18n class**.

I followed the example of the following [github](https://github.com/ilteoood/flutter_i18n/tree/master/example); but it seems like the error being triggered is from the plugin's base library itself. Can anybody help me?

Error shown on android emulator:

[image: Error Shown on Android Emulator]

Comment: Did you add the jsons for the languages you want support?

Comment: @AdemirVillenaZevallos Yes I have added the json files I want to support and the plugin inner function even says the json file has been loaded. [link] (https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/44058187/72146799-2b433a00-33d8-11ea-8782-d4eb7f4bb836.png)